# How to transform an array to another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to transform an array of object in another array but i didn't find the right way to do it.

This is my initial array :

```php
      Array (
        object(Event1){
          'event_name' => 'xxxx',
          'event_start_date' => '2020-12-12',
        }
        object(Event2){
          'event_name' => 'xxxx', // same name, diff date
          'event_start_date' => '2020-12-13',
        }
        object(Event3){
          'event_name' => 'yyyy', // new name, diff date
          'event_start_date' => '2020-12-14',
        }
        object(Event4){
          'event_name' => 'yyyy', 
          'event_start_date' => '2020-12-15',
        }
      )
```

What i want to have for result

```js
Array(
        'xxxx' => array('2020-12-12','2020-12-13')
        'yyyy' => array('2020-12-14','2020-12-15')
      )
```

What i have done so far :

```php
$datesArray = array();
$newEventDatesArray = array();

foreach ($eventsbookable as $event){
 if( $newEventDatesArray[0] != $event->event_name  ){
  $datesArray[] = $event->event_start_date;
  $tempArray = array($event->event_name, $datesArray);
  $newEventDatesArray[0] = $tempArray ;
 } else {
  $newEventDatesArray[0][1][] =  $event->event_start_date ;
 }
}
```

but this produce something far from useful :

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Grand écart
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2019-09-19
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Grand écart
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2019-09-19
                    [1] => 2019-09-20
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Piece for person and ghetto blaster
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2019-09-19
                    [1] => 2019-09-20
                    [2] => 2019-09-21
                )

        )

)
```

I know (i'm quite sure) this question is already on SO but i have searched a lot and didn't find the right answer this time, so i'm making my first post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `foreach` do it like this,

```
foreach ($eventsbookable as $event){
    $newEventDatesArray[$event->event_name][] =  $event->event_start_date ;
}
```